# Command Return as Variable

Tags: file, shell, unix, for-loop, variable-assignment

I have a problem when trying to get the variables values from an external file.
My question is: Is it possible to read the value from the file in a for and then using the cut command I can get the information before the = that will be the variable and after the = that will be the value. This is what I tried below but that is not permitted:

```
for i in `cat $1`
do
    `echo $i | cut -d= -f1`=`echo $i | cut -d= -f2`
done
```

The $1 is the file that was passed as parameter and that has 3 lines in which line there is a variable and the value in the format **variable=value** .
Is there a way that I can do this instead of need to get the variable names and then another for condition for the values of these variables ? Or even if my code is right but just need to change something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
source $1
```

example:

```
$ cat file.txt 
var1=123
var2=234

$ cat my.sh 
#!/bin/bash
source $1
echo $var1

$ ./my.sh file.txt 
123
```

Or use "let" if "for" loop so important for you.

```
for i in `cat $1`
do
    let `echo $i | cut -d= -f1`=`echo $i | cut -d= -f2`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply through this:

```
while read -r LINE; do
    echo "${LINE#*=}"  ## Delete all values before and including = then, echo it.
done < "$1"
```